# how to achieve real transaction in spring with @Transactional

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, transactions

I have 2 repositories - every repository have save methods for different object.
I want to execute these two methods as transaction, which means if one of them fail, the transaction will be rolled back. (this is the meaning of transaction in my opinion).

Here is my code:

```
@Repository
public class BananaRep {

    private JdbcTemplate jdbc;

    @Autowired
    public BananaRep(JdbcTemplate jdbc) {
        this.jdbc = jdbc;
    }

    public void saveBanana(Banana banana) {
        jdbc.update("insert into ......", ...);
    }
}

@Repository
public class TomatoRep {
    private JdbcTemplate jdbc;

    @Autowired
    public TomatoRep(JdbcTemplate jdbc) {
        this.jdbc = jdbc;
    }

    public void saveTomato(Tomato tomato) {
        jdbc.update("insert into ... ", ....);
    }
}

@RestController
public class MixController {
    @Autowired
    BananaRep bananaRep;
    @Autowired
    TomatoRep tomatoRep;

    @Transactional
    @RequestMapping(value="/mix", method= RequestMethod.GET)
    public Car mix() {

        Banana banana = new Banana(....);
        bananaRep.saveBanana(banana );

        Tomato tomato= new Tomato(...);
        tomatoRep.saveTomato(tomato);
        return banana;
    }
}
```

my build:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '2.0.0.M2'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/snapshot" }
        maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/milestone" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/snapshot" }
    maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/milestone" }
}


dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jersey')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc')
    compile('mysql:mysql-connector-java')
}
```

In order to test it I change the name of one db column in the Tomato table, so in  my controller saveTomato(tomato) method will fail. I want if this happen saved banana to be rolled back. I thought it should work like this with  @Transactional method annotation but I am wrong.

How to achieve my goal then?

Comment: You are not using spring-boot, are you? If not, have you declared the `DataSourceTransactionManager`? Show your config, please.

Comment: please maintain the session factory and Transaction Objects.

Comment: Are you creating your datasource using `@EnableAutoConfiguration`? You should have a `DataSourceTransactionManager` bean created by Spring automatically.

Comment: I dont have @EnableAutoConfiguration and I dont need it. Its spring boot. But I cannot make a transaction with 2 queries in fact. It is silly if spring framework cannot achieve this. #alfcope

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I used MyISAM in MySQL table and they do not support transactions. That was big problem for me. I hope my solution help other people like me.

Answer (score 1):

```
@Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

@Transactional
    @RequestMapping(value="/mix", method= RequestMethod.GET)
    public Car mix() {
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        Banana banana = new Banana(....);
        bananaRep.saveBanana(banana );

        Tomato tomato= new Tomato(...);
        tomatoRep.saveTomato(tomato);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        return banana;
    }
```

For the bean :

```
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaSessionFactoryBean;

 @Bean
    public HibernateJpaSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory(){
        return new HibernateJpaSessionFactoryBean();
    }
```

I don't know if it's the best solution but in my case, that works ;)

Comment: what dependency I should add to spring boot in order to get SessionFactory ?

Comment: I think this dependency : spring-boot-starter-data-jpa

Comment: and how to configure the bean, because it says no beans of type SessionFactory found? Also is there any way with @Transactional propagation or something ? This annotation is useless otherwise.

Comment: when I put this config another class is failing with the following: Consider defining a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' in your configuration.

Comment: See if your service shouldn't be annoted Transactional and your application EnableTransactionManagement... Normally, Transactional annotation do the commit . In my case, I used sessionFactory because I had the same problem and little of time.

Comment: @ivanlirchev Consider defining a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' in your configuration. Have you EnableAutoConfiguration annotation in your main class?

Comment: no I dont need it because I have @SpringBootApplication in my main class

Answer (score 1):

Transaction control should be placed in the service business processing layer

Comment: don't look the structure. This is just an example.